# Find consecutive repeating patterns in string

Tags: string, algorithm, loops

Given a string, the goal is to find the consecutive repeating substrings in the input. There might be multiple of such repeating patterns. The string can be very large, so linear solutions are preferred. The output should be where each loop starts, where it ends, and what is the size of each repetition.

To better understand the question, think of the string as the result of a number of print statements some of which were in place inside loop(s). The goal is to find the repeating patterns, therefore the loops:

```
print(a);
print(x);
print(b);
print(r);
for(0 -> 5)
    print(x)
    print(r);
    print(b);
print(m);
print(u);
```

Which results in:

```
axbrxrbxrbxrbxrbxrbmu
```

For the above example the output would be:
Start: 4
End: 18
Size: 3

Comment: This problem is similar to the problem of dictionary-based compression, so I'd start by looking for descriptions of compression algorithms.

Comment: I don't think there's a linear algorithm because each time you find any repetition, you don't know if that sequence is part of a longer repetition that includes it (e.g. "abab" could be part of "ababcababc"). The only real shortcut you have is you only have to search for half the string (within the other half) at most, but I don't think there's any way to avoid taking every substring that's a candidate and looking for repetitions.

Comment: Would abcxabcyabcz have 'abc' repeated 3 times, or are you looking for consecutive repetitions as in the example?